# A program that counts that maximum streak of heads and tails

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, nested-if

This is what I have so far, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I am so far only able to store the total amounts of heads and tails flipped.

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int heads = 0, tails = 0;
        int usernum;
        int hc=0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Coin myCoin = new Coin();
        System.out.println("The number flips: ");
        usernum=scan.nextInt();
        for (int count = 1; count <= usernum; count++)//this is where I'm having the most trouble, as I can't figure out how to store the greatest streak for heads and tails.
        {
            myCoin.flip();//generates either 1 or 0
            if (myCoin.isHeads())//checks if the integer is equal to 1 (which is heads in this case)
            {
                heads++;
                System.out.println("Heads");
                if (heads>=hc)
                   hc++;
            }else{
                tails++;
                hc=0;
                System.out.println("Tails");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Heads: " + heads);
        System.out.println("Tails: " + tails);
    }
}
```

Comment: johndoe123 - Any update?

Comment: Thank you, I finally go it to work a while back.

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of three variables: `headStreak`, `tailStreak`, and `maxStreak`, all initialized as 0. Inside your for loop, when you encounter a head, you need to do 3 things:

1. increment `headStreak`
2. If `tailStreak` is greater than `maxStreak`, set `maxStreak` to `tailStreak`
3. set `tailStreak` to 0.

Do the same thing when you encounter a tails, except replacing `headStreak` with `tailStreak` and vice versa.

After for loop: `System.println(Math.max(Math.max(headStreak, tailStreak), maxStreak))`. If you implemented the steps correctly, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the following algorithm to solve this:

1. You can use two variables, say `headStreak` and `tailStreak` to keep track of the respective streaks. When the streak breaks, reset them to `1`.
2. You can use two variables, say `maxTailStreak` and `maxHeadStreak` to keep track of the maximum of the respective streaks.
3. You can use a variable, say `last` to keep track of the result of the last flip. Start with `last = -1` and set it to `1` in case of `Heads`, and `0` in case of `Tails`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Coin {
    Random random = new Random();
    int result;

    public void flip() {
        result = random.nextInt(2);
    }

    public boolean isHeads() {
        return result == 1;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int heads = 0, tails = 0;
        int usernum;
        int headStreak = 0, tailStreak = 0, last = -1, maxTailStreak = 0, maxHeadStreak = 0;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Coin myCoin = new Coin();
        System.out.print("The number flips: ");
        usernum = scan.nextInt();
        for (int count = 1; count <= usernum; count++) {
            myCoin.flip();
            if (myCoin.isHeads()) {
                heads++;
                System.out.println("Heads");
                if (last == 1 || last == -1) {
                    headStreak++;
                    if (headStreak >= maxHeadStreak) {
                        maxHeadStreak = headStreak;
                    }
                } else {
                    headStreak = 1;
                }
                last = 1;
            } else {
                tails++;
                System.out.println("Tails");
                if (last == 0 || last == -1) {
                    tailStreak++;
                    if (tailStreak >= maxTailStreak) {
                        maxTailStreak = tailStreak;
                    }
                } else {
                    tailStreak = 1;
                }
                last = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Heads: " + heads);
        System.out.println("Tails: " + tails);
        System.out.println("The longest streak of Heads: " + maxHeadStreak);
        System.out.println("The longest streak of Tails: " + maxTailStreak);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
The number flips: 10
Tails
Tails
Tails
Tails
Tails
Heads
Heads
Heads
Tails
Tails
Heads: 3
Tails: 7
The longest streak of Heads: 3
The longest streak of Tails: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a counter for each streak and and get the maximum like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    int heads = 0, tails = 0;
    int usernum;
    int longestHeadStreak = 0, currentHeadStreak = 0, longestTailStreak = 0, currentTailStreak = 0  ;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Coin myCoin = new Coin();
    System.out.println("The number flips: ");
    usernum=scan.nextInt();
    for (int count = 1; count <= usernum; count++)//this is where I'm having the most trouble, as I can't figure out how to store the greatest streak for heads and tails.
    {
        myCoin.flip();//generates either 1 or 0
        if (myCoin.isHeads())//checks if the integer is equal to 1 (which is heads in this case)
        {
            currentTailStreak = 0;
            currentHeadStreak ++;
            System.out.println("Heads");
            if (currentHeadStreak>longestHeadStreak)
               longestHeadStreak=currentHeadStreak;
        }else{
            if (currentTailStreak>longestTailStreak) {
                longestTailStreak=currentTailStreak;
            }
            currentHeadStreak = 0;
            currentTailStreak++;
            System.out.println("Tails");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max streak of Heads: " + longestHeadStreak);
    System.out.println("Max streaks of Tails: " + longestTailStreak);
}
```